# Grouping line objects that touch vertex to vertex in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, vector

I am looking for solution in QGIS (PyQGIS welcomed) that given a set of objects (or a layer) groups them if touch each other vertex to vertex but not if only cross each other or touch segment to vertex. So for example:

[image: Before]

And here is the desired result:

[image: After]

Is there any tool or solution to perform such grouping?

Edit:
I am planning to use the algorithm on a layer representing forest roads. It can contain few hundreds objects, but I am interested in using it on subsets based on administrative division, so probably around 20 objects at once on average.

Comment: How many such objects that overlap are you likely to test for vertex-to-vertex intersect? 3 like you show or millions? What do these lines represent? A network would give you a data structure to test for node-intersections. Edit you question and provide more detail.

Comment: @Hornbydd More details provided.

Comment: Pyshp is an easy way to read geometries.  This gives you a Python list of coordinates for a lines vertices. Check the other line geometries, if you have the same coordinates in two geometry lists you have a vertex match, attribute  matches with a new value that you can use to dissolve when the script completes.

Answer (score 3):

1. Extract start points of the line. Use [Geometry by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisgeometrybyexpression) with this expression: `start_point ($geometry)`
2. Run the tool [`Service area (from layer)`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html#qgisserviceareafromlayer) with the points created in step 1 as start points. Define large enough travel costs (covering the whole length of all connected lines) and maybe a small toplogy tolerance (like 0.1 meter) in case the start points are not exactly snapped to the line.
3. Run [`Delete duplicate geometries`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisdeleteduplicategeometries).

*Vertices (red) and start points (white) with the resulting lines:*
[image]

Comment: Nice solution, but it also works on vertex-segment connections and I can't have that. It also seems to slightly modify geometry of the network (input and output layer don't intersect completely)

Comment: That's strange. As you can see on the updated screenshot, vertex-segment connections result in separate lines (red and blue ones: end point of red line is on a segment of the blue line). Also I can't reproduce the behaviour that input and output do not intersect completely. I don't know what that is the case with your data. Can you provide sample data for testing?

Comment: I checked again and as for input and output not intersecting it turns out it was just weird rendering. About the other thing - I am absolutely sure that in my case vertex-segment connection does not separate lines. I could provide sample layer, but it is exactly what you did - few random lines with different types of relations to each other.

Comment: vertex-segment connection does not separate lines: this might have to do with the fact that you choase a too big toplogy tolerance. Reduce it to 0 to see what happens. Maybe also the CRS your data is saved in plays a role.

Answer (score 3):

The "Disconnected Islands" plugin can be used to do exactly this operation.
[image]

it gives this result (using the created attribute in a categorized renderer since the geometries aren't modified)
[image]

In the rightmost example, both lines share an identical vertex

If you are interested in the explanation of what the plugin does it is really simple. It turns the layer into a graph and calculates the connected components of the graph which does exactly what you described by "groups them if touch each other vertex to vertex but not if only cross each other or touch segment to vertex".